# Fotorama 4. Slide more than 1 image

Tags: javascript, jquery, fotorama

I'm using Fotorama.js
[fotorama.io](http://fotorama.io)

How to add in view more than 1 image using fotorama.js? 
I'd like to make carousel with this plugin.

```
    <div class="fotorama">
       <div data-img="images/main/slider/big.jpg">
                <div class="slide-text">
                    <div class="slide-header">
                       Heading
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide-description">
                       Description
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       <div data-img="images/main/slider/big2.jpg">
                <div class="slide-text">
                    <div class="slide-header">
                       Heading
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide-description">
                       Description
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2zrh.png

Comment: Show us your existing codes.

Comment: That's all. It standard API of fotorama

Comment: The examples are quite different from your codes: http://fotorama.io/customize/

Comment: http://fotorama.io/customize/html/

The last one

Answer (score 0):

Try to download latest version of fotorama and check the paths to css and js like it declared on [fotorama.io](http://fotorama.io):

```
<!-- 1. Link to jQuery (1.8 or later), -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> <!-- 32 KB -->

<!-- fotorama.css & fotorama.js. -->
<link  href="http://fotorama.s3.amazonaws.com/4.4.4/fotorama.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- 3 KB -->
<script src="http://fotorama.s3.amazonaws.com/4.4.4/fotorama.js"></script> <!-- 13 KB -->
```

Because your example works perfectly for me: [example](http://jsbin.com/irezoWu/3/edit)

Comment: Yes it is. But my idea is to make carousel with more than 1 block on each slide.

Comment: Fotorama can be like carousel if you turn on autoplay mode. Do you want to do carousel inside carousel, did I get this right?

Comment: As I concerned Fotorama doesn't able to do this, you might want to look at carouFredSel plugin, it's also free: http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/

Comment: Do you know about how to solve this ? https://github.com/artpolikarpov/fotorama/issues/521